# On MacOS Catalina how do you remove items from the Open With menu?

Tags: macos-catalina

A bit of a beginner Mac question but I can't see a way to remove older versions of VS Code from my 'Open With ...' menu.

All other apps seem to correctly overwrite themselves so there is only one of them. Like 'Safari'. But VS Code seems to add a version number, sigh.

I want only *one* entry for VS Code. The latest one.

This is what I'm currently seeing:

[image]

Comment: There must be multiple applications of vscode, delete the vscode from applications tab, and download-install again.

Comment: @Alia There is only one vscode in the Applications tab. I can't attach an image in a comment it seems, but only one "Visual Studio Code.app" is listed there. I can't see where the "Open With" is being populated. Is there an internal list/registry or something I can delete?